# "intellisense" for a text field on webpage

Tags: asp.net, sql, textfield

I am not sure how to describe this but I'm gonna try. So you have a text field on a webpage and in this field you enter in the last name of someone that you want to leave a comment about. If someone has already commented on this exact person then when you are typing smith,john by the time you get to "Smit" below the text box it will say "Smith,John" and you can just click on that. If Smith,John doesn't exist then it will create a new record in the database so when the next person tries to comment on Smith, John it will show up for them. It would be like an intellisense for the text box and it checks the database for the record.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this with javascript. Try googling.

Comment: This is called autocomplete. There are many, many implementations available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like the [jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget.](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Well thanks for the quick answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know how to word it.